ngRecaptcha plugin integration with Angular 18 standalone component
While trying to install ngRecaptcha in stanalone component in Angular 18 project, it was giving error while trying to install it, Can any please help me with error or suggest any alternate plugin for the same functionality in Angular 18
Solution and fix for above error.
